# Filter duplicates in a batch arguments array

Tags: batch-file, filter, cmd

I'm writing a batch, where a user must input a list of devices to activate as batch arguments. The list may contain device numbers and/or names in random order with possible duplicates and invalids (i.e. non-existing or not Ready devices). The batch *:default* section stores an array *dev_#=name* of all currently Ready devices in random order. The initial task is to filter the user input to exclude duplicates and invalids, and present a list of sorted ready device numbers to activate. Then the devices from that list are activated. What efficient short code would do the filtering task?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:default
set "dev_1=AB" & set "dev_2=BA" & set "dev_3=AC" & set "dev_16=CA" & set "dev_19=BC" & set "dev_6=CB" & set "dev_7=ZA"
set "dev_8=AZ" & set "dev_29=UA" & set "dev_10=YZ" & set "dev_18=YW" & set "dev_12=AK" & set "dev_13=AJ" & set "dev_14=HT"

rem batch arguments entered by user
rem 1 3 6 AB BA YZ 12 17 21 YK AU AK BA BU ZA

rem Desired sorted filtered output
rem 1 2 3 6 7 10 12
```

Comment: If this is related to your previous question then your batch file is way too complicated. Either rethink what you are doing or write a program instead. You are trying to do things that batch files are not really designed to do.

Comment: While this is not related to any of my previous questions, I'd appreciate a referral to any MS source which defines what batch files were designed to do, as well as suggestions what tool would be more appropriate for the task. I know some people can code batching tasks at the level of true art.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One liner with native batch commands - no way!

But it doesn't take a lot of code, especially if you are creative with designing some data structures. Note that the only code that counts is the `:test` routine. The rest is intitialization and test cases.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Clear devices
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set dev. 2^>nul') do set "%%A="

:: Define devices
for %%A in (
  " 1=AB" " 2=BA" " 3=AC" "16=CA" "19=BC" " 6=CB" " 7=ZA"
  " 8=AZ" "29=UA" "10=YZ" "18=YW" "12=AK" "13=AJ" "14=HI"
) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (%%A) do for %%N in (%%a) do (
  set "dev.%%N= %%a"
  set "dev.%%b= %%a"
)

call :test 1 3 6 AB BA YZ 12 17 21 YK AU AK BA BU ZA
call :test sadf asdfa
call :test aj 6 13 CB
exit /b

:test
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Clear selected
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set selected. 2^>nul') do set "%%A="

:loadArgs  Define a variable for each unique device specified in args
if "%~1" neq "" (
  if defined dev.%~1 set "selected.!dev.%~1!=1"
  shift /1
  goto :loadArgs
)

:: Write out the unique values in sorted order
set "dev= "
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%A in ('set selected. 2^>nul') do set "dev=!dev!%%A "
echo selected devices = %dev:~1%

exit /b
```

--OUTPUT--

```
selected devices = 1 2 3 6 7 10 12
selected devices =
selected devices = 6 13
```

If you are confident that users will never include `*`, `?`, or `)` within the arguments, then a FOR loop can replace the GOTO loop. The `:test` routine simplifies to the following:

```
:test
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Clear selected
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set selected. 2^>nul') do set "%%A="

:: Define a variable for each unique device specified in args
for %%A in (%*) do if defined dev.%%~A set "selected.!dev.%%~A!=1"

:: Write out the unique values in sorted order
set "dev= "
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%A in ('set selected. 2^>nul') do set "dev=!dev!%%A "
echo selected devices = %dev:~1%

exit /b
```

Now if you are willing to step outside the bounds of pure native batch, then a one liner is certainly doable. I would use my [JSORT.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) and [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) utilities. JSORT is able to sort numbers, so leading spaces are no longer needed in the initialization values.

Now the `:test` routine is truly a one liner:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Clear devices
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set dev. 2^>nul') do set "%%A="

:: Define devices
for %%A in (
  "1=AB" "2=BA" "3=AC" "16=CA" "19=BC" "6=CB" "7=ZA"
  "8=AZ" "29=UA" "10=YZ" "18=YW" "12=AK" "13=AJ" "14=HI"
) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims== " %%a in (%%A) do (
  set "dev.%%a=%%a"
  set "dev.%%b=%%a"
)

call :test 1 3 6 AB BA YZ 12 17 21 YK AU AK BA BU ZA
call :test sadf asdfa
call :test aj 6 13 CB
exit /b

:test
(for %%A in (. %*) do @call echo(%%dev.%%A%%) | jsort /n /u | jrepl "(\s|%%.*?%%)+" " " /m | jrepl "^ " ""
exit /b
```

or

```
:test
echo(%*|jrepl "(^|\s*)(\S+)" "env('dev.'+$2)" /jmatch | jsort /n /u | jrepl "\s+" " " /m | jrepl "^ " ""
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. There might be a typo in the GOTO section (closing double quote missing), but for some reason it doesn't give an error on my system: `"selected.!dev.%~1!=1` ?

Comment: @sambul35 - Yes, you were right. I fixed the code. As you have seen, the closing quote is not required, but it is bad form not to include it. Without the closing quote, any trailing spaces on the line would be included in the assigned value. With the closing quote, any remaining characters are ignored.

Comment: Strange thing is, when I miss a closing double quote, the code always gives an error. But your code works even with this typo. Why is that?

Comment: @sambul35 - There is no simple answer. It all depends on the context. General rule of thumb - "always" provide the closing quote, unless there is a specific reason why you shouldn't.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent automatic variables sorting in ('set dev.')? Its desirable in some cases, like changing their  values from 0 to values supplied as batch arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to alternatives, here is an example in [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) (save in a file with `.vbs` extension instead of `.bat` ):

```
input = InputBox("", , "1 3 6 AB BA YZ 12 17 21 YK AU AK BA BU ZA")
values = Split(input)

' Adds the values to a sorted list that matches the case    
Set list = CreateObject( "System.Collections.Sortedlist" )    
For Each value in values
   Select Case value
      Case "1" , "AB" : list(1 ) = 0
      Case "2" , "BA" : list(2 ) = 0
      Case "3" , "AC" : list(3 ) = 0
      Case "6" , "CB" : list(6 ) = 0
      Case "7" , "ZA" : list(7 ) = 0
      Case "8" , "AZ" : list(8 ) = 0
      Case "10", "YZ" : list(10) = 0
      Case "12", "AK" : list(12) = 0
      Case "13", "AJ" : list(13) = 0
      Case "14", "HT" : list(14) = 0
      Case "16", "CA" : list(16) = 0
      Case "18", "YW" : list(18) = 0
      Case "19", "BC" : list(19) = 0
      Case "29", "UA" : list(29) = 0
   End Select
Next

' To show the items in the list   
For i = 0 To list.Count - 1
    output = output & list.GetKey(i) & " "
Next
MsgBox output
```

Another alternative is PowerShell (extension `.ps1`):

```
$s = "1 3 6 AB BA YZ 12 17 21 YK AU AK BA BU ZA"
$a = -split $s 

$a = $a -replace "AB", 1
$a = $a -replace "BA", 2
$a = $a -replace "AC", 3
$a = $a -replace "CB", 6
$a = $a -replace "ZA", 7
$a = $a -replace "AZ", 8
$a = $a -replace "YZ", 10
$a = $a -replace "AK", 12
$a = $a -replace "AJ", 13
$a = $a -replace "HT", 14
$a = $a -replace "CA", 16
$a = $a -replace "YW", 18
$a = $a -replace "BC", 19
$a = $a -replace "UA", 29

$a = $a | ? { -split "1 2 3 6 7 8 10 12 13 14 16 18 19 29" -contains $_ }
$l = $a | % { iex $_ }
$l = $l | sort-object -Unique 
$l -join " "
```

But running a PowerShell script is a bit challenging, so instead you can run it from a `.bat` file like this:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "&{"^
 "$s = '1 3 6 AB BA YZ 12 17 21 YK AU AK BA BU ZA' ;"^
 "$a = -split $s ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'AB', 1  ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'BA', 2  ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'AC', 3  ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'CB', 6  ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'ZA', 7  ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'AZ', 8  ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'YZ', 10 ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'AK', 12 ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'AJ', 13 ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'HT', 14 ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'CA', 16 ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'YW', 18 ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'BC', 19 ;"^
 "$a = $a -replace 'UA', 29 ;"^
 "$a = $a | ? { -split '1 2 3 6 7 8 10 12 13 14 16 18 19 29' -contains $_ } ;"^
 "$l = $a | %% { iex $_ } ;"^
 "$l = $l | sort-object -Unique ;"^
 "$l -join ' ' ;"^
 "}"

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an extended comment to show an application example for readers of native Cmd sorting used in Dave's above answer. It requires padding numbered vars with zeros.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "devs= 1 10 12 2 3 4 6 7 8 9"
for %%k in (!devs!) do (set /a "devl=100+%%k" & set "devl=!devl:~-2!"
    set "dev.!devl!=!devl!")
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%l in ('set dev.') do set "devn=!devn! %%l"
echo !devn!

exit /b

:: output
:: 01 02 03 04 06 07 08 09 10 12
```